# WPF TabControl Position Tabs in the top right corner

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, direction

I have a WPF `TabControl` that I want to position the tabs with a `TabStripPlacement` of `Top`, but I want them to display with a right orientation on top. I've achieved that easily by doing a `FlowDirection` of `RightToLeft`; however, I don't want the children controls to inherit the `RightToLeft` `FlowDirection`.

Is there any way to position the tabs on the top on the right without using the `FlowDirection` property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, you could always try creating a custom style for the `TabControl` to specify how the tabs are laid out.  Alternatively, just use `FlowDirection` and specify the `FlowDirection` as `LeftToRight` on each individual `TabItem` so the child controls display normally.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply! I should clarify that I am setting the FlowDirection of each TabItem to LeftToRight which works on the display side. I'm trying to accomplish the following: http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/01/03/taking-wpf-screenshots/. The screenshots are captured, but they are backwards when the TabControl FlowDirection is set to RightToLeft.

Comment: I took your suggestion and used a custom style and set the TabPanel tag's FlowDirection like so: <TabPanel Grid.Row="0" IsItemsHost="true" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>. Then I left the TabControl's FlowDirection to RightToLeft. This achieved what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

This question is old, but it is what came up when I google searched. The answer wasn't really what I wanted. So I researched this in Expresion Blend. I determined that the TabPanel needs to have HorizontalAlignment="Right" style. So for future, it is as easy as this:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabPanel">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.Items>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 1"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 2"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 3"></TabItem>
    </TabControl.Items>
</TabControl>
```

Let me know if you see any issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Rhyous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22516784/2497944), but with fixing tabs arrangement

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabPanel">
            <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.Items>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 1"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 2"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 3"></TabItem>
    </TabControl.Items>
</TabControl>
```